# Open microsoft website if .net framework 3.5 not install during installation

Tags: installshield, installscript, .net-framework-version

I am creating Installshield setup to install my software,my software check first .net framework 3.5 installed or not?

```
#define EXAMPLE_DIR "D:\\"



if(!Is(DOTNETFRAMEWORKINSTALLED,REGDB_KEYPATH_DOTNET_35)) then
     return1=AskYesNo("Target system does not have .net 3.5 framework,Do you want to install?",YES);
        if(return1==YES) then
            LaunchApp(EXAMPLE_DIR^"website.bat","");
        else
            abort;
        endif;
   endif;
```

it check the framework perfectly but now I want that if user click on the yes button the site of microsoft should be open?

Any one idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I would just use the Prerequisite support. For the last several versions prerequisites are available in both MSI- and InstallScript-based projects.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this...........

```
//#define EXAMPLE_DIR "D:\\"



if(!Is(DOTNETFRAMEWORKINSTALLED,REGDB_KEYPATH_DOTNET_35)) then
     return1=AskYesNo("Target system does not have .net 3.5 framework,Do you want to install?",YES);
        if(return1==YES) then
            LaunchApp(SUPPORTDIR^"website.bat","");
        else
            abort;
        endif;
   endif;
```